# Software Center Will Not Install From Terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

When trying to install Software Center I get the following message:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

How can I get the Software Center back or how can I install software without it?

Comment: it depends which software you want to install, if it is available in the official ubuntu repositories or not. The Software help center is available on your Ubuntu, it is likely to be visible as an icon on your desktop. Which version are you running?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Why is it not installed already?

Comment: I am currently using Ubuntu 14.10 . When the software center was not connecting to the INTERNET I sought out a solution via Ask Ubuntu. I found and tried a few different potential solutions but ended up losing the software center completely.

Comment: NOTE: If I upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 I will not be able to connect to the Internet. That is a whole other issue I was dealing with yesterday so I downgraded back to Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is no longer supported since July 2015. Please install a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: If I UPDATE/UPGRADE to 15.04 I wont have an internet connection. That is a whole other issue that I was having yesterday. Thats why I downgraded.

Comment: Use 14.04 or 15.10. 14.10 has security issues that won't be fixed, and you won't be able to install the majority of software anyway since support was dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes first, update to a current version.

Second, you don't really need a GUI for the Software Center. The only advantage that I see in having the GUI is that its easier to discover new and different programs, than through the command line (But you can do still do it).

Finally, why can't you access the Internet aftervthe upgrade?

Comment: When I upgraded I was not able to access public WiFi for some reason.

Comment: After almost 10 years of full on loyalty to Ubuntu I am finally saying goodbye and switching back to windows. I never thought that I would see the day when Ubuntu had more issues than Windows. It was a great OS but over the years it has veered off track. I hope that one day It'll get back on track but I don't see it happening any time soon. .

Comment: Sorry,the system won't let me add another answer, but after you did th